# My subtotal calculating twice of total price not sure why?

Tags: magento-1.9

Why my subtotal showing wrong values on checkout page. When i am trying to add a product to cart. It is showing twice value of order.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the template file for your checkout page. Then I would look for Observers in modules that modify the checkout page. Most likely some code is looping through twice when adding the totals.

Comment: Can you please send me the file path which you want to check. so that it will be easy for both :) thanks